# pass /all/ args from python to bash script

Tags: python, bash, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

this is for KODI, i need to run the bash script with systemd-run from python or i get a black screen. and the frontend doesnt open

so far, i have this which can pass ONE argument to the bash script if one or more argument, or none if no arguments. the latter being the part i need help with.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, sys


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        arg=str(sys.argv[1])
        print ("arg is %s" % arg)
        subprocess.call(["systemd-run /usr/bin/emulator-frontend.sh %s" % str(sys.argv[1])], shell=True)
else:

        subprocess.call(["systemd-run /usr/bin/emulator-frontend.sh"], shell=True)
```

seeing as im using one script to call another script im trying to be as elegant as possible, if this can happen without an if statement id love it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't combine a list argument with `shell=True`. Use either

```
subprocess.call("systemd-run /usr/bin/emulator-frontend.sh", shell=True)
```

or

```
subprocess.call(["systemd-run", "/usr/bin/emulator-frontend.sh"])
```

If you want to pass the Python script's arguments directly to the subprocess, just concatenate the lists:

```
subprocess.call(["systemd-run", "/usr/bin/emulator-frontend.sh"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Note that if there are no arguments, `sys.argv[1:]` is empty, and the list of hard-coded arguments is left unchanged, with no need for an explicit conditional.

Comment: It might make sense to lead with the best-practice answer at the end.

Comment: when i didnt use brackets and shell=true it caused problems that i had no view-able output to use to diagnose. ended in a black screen and a reboot.